# jQuery and Ajax script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So i have a jQuery script that i should explain it line by line, i already do that and i want to make sure that is correct, so this is my script :

```
 //Here we use the jQuery selector ($) to select the servers_id which is located into  
//the delivers_id and we attaches a function to run when a change event occurs

 $("#delivers #servers").change(function(){

//Here we look if the servers_id value was changed and the value is different of 0

    if($(this).val() != '0') {

//Here we create a new variable sid and we stored the servers_id value in it
        var sid = $("#delivers #servers").val();

//Here we use the Ajax $.get to get the sid value and send it by Ajax request then 
//we set the data into the o_vmats_id html and empty the vmtas_id
        $.get("/deliverability/get_vmtas/" + sid,
        function(data) { $('#o_vmtas').html(data); $('#vmtas').html(''); });
    } 

//Here the else statement, we select the vmtas_id and set the html content like in the code (value=0)
//and empty the o_vmtas_id html content
    else { $('#vmtas').html('<option value="0">All Classes</option>');  

     $('#o_vmtas').html(''); }
});
```

so please if someone has any remark i will be very appreciative

Comment: Ids must be unique, therefore you can just call `$("#servers")`, otherwise make each element's id unique or consider using classes.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the #servers element twice, no need for that. You can and should cache items that are going to be looked up more than once, so store that element in a var at the very beginning.

Other than that... there's not much to it, other than you wouldn't actually need much jQuery to do this :)

Comment: Thnx Ricardo yes i know that, but actually it is not my script i just explain what is going on,